Nested Enum with Protobuf in an AAOS Project
I am working on a Rust project that involves using Protocol Buffers within the Android Automotive OS (AAOS) environment, and dealing with nested enums. Here's what I have so far in Rust:
enum Vehicle {
    Car(CarType),
    Truck(TruckType),
}

enum CarType {
    Sedan,
    Coupe,
    Hatchback,
}

enum TruckType {
    Pickup,
    Semi,
}

fn create_vehicle_fleet() -> [Vehicle; 8] {
    [
        Vehicle::Car(CarType::Sedan),
        Vehicle::Truck(TruckType::Pickup),
        Vehicle::Car(CarType::Coupe),
        Vehicle::Truck(TruckType::Semi),
        Vehicle::Car(CarType::Hatchback),
        Vehicle::Car(CarType::Sedan),
        Vehicle::Truck(TruckType::Pickup),
        Vehicle::Car(CarType::Coupe),
    ]
}

I am trying to map these Rust enums to Protocol Buffers for use in AAOS. However, I am encountering limitations because the  IDL used in AAOS is designed to handle simple enum types, but not message types
I cannot find a proper way to represent the Vehicle enum in protobuf. Can anyone suggest a solution or provide guidance on how to handle this situation in Protocol Buffers?

Have you read the documentation of protobuf, especially wrt. the trait Enum?

I suspect (!?) because of the language-independence of Protocol Buffers, you can't always represent language-specific types using protos directly.
In this case, Rust has powerful, complex enum types but Protocol Buffers only permits constant enums.
I think (!?) a near equivalent to what you need is:
syntax = "proto3";

// package something;

// Only messages can hold repeateds
message Foo {
    repeated Vehicle vehicles = 1;
}

// oneof permits the equivalent of a enum of non-constant types
// In some languages, the oneof name is lost but in rust it is retained
// See code snippet below
message Vehicle {
  oneof vehicle_type {
    CarType car_type = 1;
    TruckType truck_type = 2;
  }
}
// Constant enums
// If CarType|TruckType ever need fields too,
// this enum would need to be oneof
enum CarType {
  Sedan = 0;
  Coupe = 1;
  Hatchback = 2;
}
enum TruckType {
  Pickup = 0;
  Semi = 1;
}

And, e.g.:
pub mod anoynmous {
    tonic::include_proto!("_");
}

use anonymous::{
    vehicle::VehicleType,
    CarType,
    Foo,
    TruckType,
    Vehicle,
};

fn main() {
    let _ = Foo {
        vehicles: vec![
            Vehicle {
                vehicle_type: Some(VehicleType::CarType(CarType::Sedan.into())),
            },
            Vehicle {
                vehicle_type: Some(VehicleType::TruckType(TruckType::Pickup.into())),
            },
        ],
    };
}


Thank you for your response. Theoretically, using a message structure should work, but I will be using the protobuf with Google's tooling(idl of AAOS) to generate publisher code. Unfortunately, this IDL setup can only handle enum types effectively. When I try to use message types as suggested, I encounter errors.

What is AAOS? Please consider updating your question to include these additional requirements

AAOS stands for Android Automotive OS. The IDL that generates publisher code, struggles with message types
